# Django application deployed on Railway.app experiencing repeated worker timeouts and SIGKILL signals

Tags: django, gunicorn, sigkill, worker-timeout

I have deployed a Django application on Railway.app, utilizing Gunicorn 21.2.0 as the WSGI server. However, I'm encountering a persistent issue where the workers are timing out and subsequently being terminated with a SIGKILL signal. Here's a snippet of the logs:

```
[2024-02-13 07:26:54 +0000] [7] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:22)
[2024-02-13 07:26:55 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Worker (pid:22) was sent SIGKILL! Perhaps out of memory?
...
[2024-02-13 07:35:04 +0000] [7] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:54)
[2024-02-13 07:35:05 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Worker (pid:54) was sent SIGKILL! Perhaps out of memory?
```

This pattern repeats consistently, with workers timing out and subsequently being killed. The application appears to be experiencing memory issues, as suggested by the error message.

I've tried adjusting various configurations, such as increasing worker timeouts but the problem persists.
Has anyone encountered similar issues while deploying Django applications on Railway.app? Any insights or suggestions on how to diagnose and resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Server Metrics**

[image]

Comment: It looks your app need more resources for startup, ex load db, model, .... what is your number worker?

Comment: @TanThien I was able to relove this by increasing the worker time out  `gunicorn core.wsgi --timeout 300`